# "Invalid memory address" while testing in Go

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have a simple Go function which I want to test:

```
func root(c echo.Context) error {
    return c.String(http.StatusOK, "This is the root!")
}
```

My tests look like this:

```
import (
    "net/http"
    "testing"

    "github.com/labstack/echo"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

type Context struct {
    echo.Context
}

func TestRoot(t *testing.T) {
    c := new(Context)
    expectedResult := c.String(http.StatusOK, "This is the root!")
    actualResult := c.String(http.StatusOK, "This is the root!")

    assert.Equal(t, expectedResult, actualResult, "they should be equal")
}
```

Now, when I run the test, I am getting this error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
        panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

I am fairly new to Go and just want to try to make sense of it. I get it that when I address an object which does not exist, I am getting this error. But every variable assignment I am doing has no change to be `nil`.

> Can somebody point me to a solution? Or tell me how simple unit tests should look like in Go?

Comment: Your `Context` type has an embedded interface; `echo.Context`, which needs a value. I'm not sure what you're trying to do here exactly, since you're not working with any Requests or Responses.

Comment: The `TestRoot` function must set c.Context to a non-nil interface value before calling methods on that interface.  Perhaps the Echo package provides a way to create such a context for tests.

Comment: That's my question. In the Unit tests I am used to do, I just test if the root function is returning the right object with a proper value. How can I do that in Go (or shouldn't I do this at all?)

Comment: @gruberb: this is part of what I don't understand, you're not even calling "root", and that function only returns the error from the String method (which will be `nil` if everything worked).  All you're doing is calling the `String`method on an interface which you left `nil`. I also don't understand what the value of comparing the 2 error values from 2 identical method calls is, since they should always be the same given the method is deterministic.

Comment: Yeah, I am not there yet. I just wanted to see how this assert works and how I create simple test data. Looks like I have to dig a bit deeper on that. Thanks for your help though!